# Что использовать: методы jQuery или нативные методы JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Возьмём для примера следующий сниппет:

```js
$('li').each(function(idx, domEl) {
  console.log('----------------------------------------');
  console.log('idx               | ' + idx              );
  console.log('domEl === this    | ' + (domEl === this) ); // true
  console.log('domEl             | ' + domEl            ); // [object HTMLLIElement]
  console.log('$(domEl).text()   | ' + $(domEl).text()  );
  console.log('domEl.textContent | ' + domEl.textContent);
  if (idx === 5) {
    return false; // to exit the loop
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
<ol>
  <li>First</li>
  <li>Second</li>
  <li>Third</li>
  <li>Fourth</li>
  <li>Fifth</li>
  <li>Sixth</li>
  <li>Seventh</li>
  <li>Eighth</li>
  <li>Ninth</li>
  <li>Tenth</li>
</ol>
```

[Фиддл](https://jsfiddle.net/5246hzqo/)

---

В данном случае, есть ли какие-то выгоды от использования этого:

```
$(domEl).text()
```

в сравнении с этим:

```
domEl.textContent
```

И что из этих двух вариантов является лучшей практикой?

Comment: если используешь jquery в проекте, смысл не пользоваться им всецело? все равно библиотека уже подгружена, а иначе смысл ее подгружать, если сможешь использовать только нативные средства?

Comment: @Jean-Claude, да, согласен с этим, здесь скорее вопрос стоит в том, что стоит ли миксовать нативные методы с методами jQuery или выбрать один стиль и использовать только его ... Думаю, отмеченный мною ответ, отвечает на мой вопрос.

Comment: Я считаю, что в 2016 году jQuery не нужен вообще

Comment: @andreymal, почему же?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Синтетические тесты такие синтетические.

Если посмотреть, что именно происходит в методе *text*

```
getText = Sizzle.getText = function( elem ) {
    var node,
        ret = "",
        i = 0,
        nodeType = elem.nodeType;

    if ( !nodeType ) {
        // If no nodeType, this is expected to be an array
        while ( (node = elem[i++]) ) {
            // Do not traverse comment nodes
            ret += getText( node );
        }
    } else if ( nodeType === 1 || nodeType === 9 || nodeType === 11 ) {
        // Use textContent for elements
        // innerText usage removed for consistency of new lines (jQuery #11153)
        if ( typeof elem.textContent === "string" ) {
            return elem.textContent;
        } else {
            // Traverse its children
            for ( elem = elem.firstChild; elem; elem = elem.nextSibling ) {
                ret += getText( elem );
            }
        }
    } else if ( nodeType === 3 || nodeType === 4 ) {
        return elem.nodeValue;
    }
    // Do not include comment or processing instruction nodes

    return ret;
};
```

можно заметить, что для примера из вопроса будет вызван - тот же самый *textContent*.

Также можно отметить, что текст функции унифицирован, чтобы ее можно было вызывать с разными типами аргументов, начиная от массива(коллекции) и заканчивая различными типами узлов: элементы, текстовые узлы и т.д.

Таким образом, если в момент написания скрипта есть точная уверенность из какого типа элементов нужно будет брать текст - можно воспользоваться необходимым свойством напрямую, для кода из вопроса - использовать *textContent* на непосредственно html элементе. Это позволит избежать расходов на вызов конструктора jQuery и соответствующие проверки внутри самой функции.

Если же неизвестно для чего будет применяться метод - то лучше воспользоваться методом jQuery.

Answer (score 3):

Метод `.text()` в jQuery позволяет получать текст не только из одиночного нода, но, например, из массива нод, отобранных по селектору. В ряде случае jQuery организует поддержку старых браузеров, в которых аналогичный ванильный метод еще не поддерживался.

Вот, например, исходники метода `.text()`:

```
function (elem) {
    var node, ret = "",
        i = 0,
        nodeType = elem.nodeType;

    if (!nodeType) {
        // If no nodeType, this is expected to be an array
        while ((node = elem[i++])) {
            // Do not traverse comment nodes
            ret += getText(node);
        }
    } else if (nodeType === 1 || nodeType === 9 || nodeType === 11) {
        // Use textContent for elements
        // innerText usage removed for consistency of new lines (jQuery #11153)
        if (typeof elem.textContent === "string") {
            return elem.textContent;
        } else {
            // Traverse its children
            for (elem = elem.firstChild; elem; elem = elem.nextSibling) {
                ret += getText(elem);
            }
        }
    } else if (nodeType === 3 || nodeType === 4) {
        return elem.nodeValue;
    }
    // Do not include comment or processing instruction nodes
    return ret;
}
```

Поддержка массива нод, корректная обработка нод с нодами-детьми вместо текста.

> Исходники методов jQuery можно просматривать [здесь](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.11.2&fn=jQuery.text).

Также есть ресурс [youmightnotneedjquery.com](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/), показывающий, каким ванильным методом можно заменить требуемый метод jQuery. Согласно ему, `.text()` можно заменить на `.textContent`, но поддержка будет только IE9+. Возможно, метод jQuery в этом плане обеспечивает поддержку и более старых браузеров.

Comment: _Возможно, метод jQuery в этом плане обеспечивает поддержку и более старых браузеров._ - зависит от версии jQuery

Comment: Спасибо за ответ и отдельное за ресурсы!